# What happens if my flight out of the Schengen area is cancelled on the last day of my visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, germany, overstaying, visa-expiration

I am a student going to Germany on guest Scientist visa. In the application form I had to fill date of departure and arrival and they have given me visa for exact dates as mentioned on my invitation letter and flight tickets booked by the research lab. Hypothetically, if my flight gets canceled on that day, will I end up violating visa duration?

EDIT: My current visa duration is only 78 days

Comment: No under unforeseen circumstances you will be given certain leeway, as mentioned to me by an official at the Finnish embassy. You might have to contact the border office at the airport if possible(not sure about this anyway).

Comment: Possible duplicate of:https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/40162/can-immigration-passport-officers-check-for-past-flight-information-of-a-passeng

Comment: No, there's a procedure for it.

Comment: @GayotFow can you please elaborate what that procedure might be?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In case of such *force majeure* that prevents you from leaving the Schengen Area within the validity period, you should contact the border authorities in the country you're in ASAP to get your visa extended with the time you need to leave.

See the [Schengen visa code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:32009R0810&from=EN), article 33.1:

> 1. The period of validity and/or the duration of stay of an issued visa shall be extended where the competent authority of a Member State considers that a visa holder has provided proof of force majeure or humanitarian reasons preventing him from leaving the territory of the Member States before the expiry of the period of validity of or the duration of stay authorised by the visa. **Such an extension shall be granted free of charge.**

The [visa code handbook](https://www.nyidanmark.dk/NR/rdonlyres/17236271-9FAE-436C-812B-DB310AFF6031/0/visa_code_handbook.pdf) (section V.1.1) explicitly mentions "last minute change of flight schedule by airline" as one example of force majeure.