# What happens if my outgoing flight is canceled on the day my French student visa expires?

Tags: visas, air-travel, schengen, long-stay-visas, missed-flights

First of all, I read the other posts similar to this case, but the two answers were conflicting.

1. [What happens if my flight out of the Schengen area is cancelled on the last day of my visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89013/what-happens-if-my-flight-out-of-the-schengen-area-is-cancelled-on-the-last-day)
2. [Can immigration/passport officers check for past flight information of a passenger?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/40162/can-immigration-passport-officers-check-for-past-flight-information-of-a-passeng)

**I have a French Type D Student Visa that is valid until August 15th. My flight flies of CDG on the night of August 14th.**

So several questions...

***What happens if my flight is delayed or cancelled past the 15th?***

When the visa says it will expire on the 15th, does that mean that I can legally leave on the 15th? Or must I leave before the 15th?

Who can I contact for more information about this case since the U.S. consulate in Paris says to not call them for Visa information?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you a US citizen?  If so, the answer is "you have 90 days".  See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79143/how-to-switch-from-resident-visa-to-tourist-visa-status-in-the-schengen-area

Comment: Go to airport. Air carrier must help you (either giving you a differet route, or accommodating you "outside France" [so putting you as in the "transfer area/hotel]). They are used by delays and such problems (consider that many visa are also very short in period, so with flights at expiration date)

Comment: 15th means end of 15th. Not start of 15th.

Comment: The US authorities have no, um, authority over your visa.  The people you should be asking are the *French* authorities.  I would start at the local *préfecture.*

Comment: @Louis some Schengen countries hold that a person in this situation must leave and reenter the Schengen area.  I don't know whether France is one of those countries, but I would avoid testing it if I were in Steve's shoes.

Comment: @phoog Maybe somebody should update this then? https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/95819/28331

Comment: @Louis I've put a comment on that answer, but note the more highly upvoted answer at https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/79146/19400: "This depends upon the host nation and if they have a policy in place for an *'in-country switch.'"*

Comment: Just wait for the next available flight. If you have cleared customs, you may be able to re-enter, but why ?  You are deemed to have departed once gateside. If you can afford it, and your need is great, and there is capacity, get a bed. .